# netsh - The following command was not found error on Windows XP

Tags: wcf, ssl, netsh

when i run the following netsh command :

netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44300 appid ={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF} certhash=dafebdb65ec7544218bf9a1794c6424 0207f63b9.

using powershell or visual studio command prompt i get the following error:

The following command was not found: http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44300 appid
={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF} certhash=dafebdb65ec7544218bf9a1794c6424
0207f63b9.

I am currently configuring a WCF service to use SSL and have been following from the book 'windows communcation foundation 4 - step-by-step' by john sharp.

I have visual studio 2010 SP1 and using IIS Express. The only difference I could think of is that i am running Windows XP Professional instead of Windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows XP `netsh` will not work properly.Better use `httpcfg`. You will need to download "WindowsXP-KB838079-SupportTools-ENU.exe" from Microsoft Download Center or try from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/838079). Change:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44300 appid ={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF} certhash=dafebdb65ec7544218bf9a1794c6424 0207f63b9
```

To

```
httpcfg set ssl -i 0.0.0.0:44300 -h dafebdb65ec7544218bf9a1794c64240207f63b9
```

This will create the SSL.
To check type

```
httpcfg query ssl
```

in `CMD`.

Hope it helps.